# Delay in .Net Remoting method calls when using IP address rather than localhost

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

There is a problem in our application server that its exposing services are implemented with .Net Remoting.

This application server has been working for years. Many customers are using it.
But recently we encountered a problem in the production server of a customer.
Server works correctly with more that 1000 concurrent users. But after a while suddenly remote method calls to application server are executed along with a significant delay. We checked and separated server business. But the delay has nothing to do with server code. The delay is before execution of any application code.

We tested with a client that is running on the server machine (same as application server), client connect to server with its IP address and problem remains. With exactly the same conditions but using localhost to connect to the server there is not any problem.

So, in summary, when using the client and server on the same machine, method calls to the server connecting with server IP address show a delay, but method calls when connecting with localhost are ok and there is no delay.

Restarting the server resolves the problem until the next time that the problem arises.

What might be causing this delay?